# PHP get data from ? in url

Tags: php

Writing a PHP file and I need to get the data from the url
ex: `example.com/viewuser.php?5555`

how would I get that the user is looking for the `5555 user` ?

don't really know what this question is or how to ask it, but I hope you understand.

Comment: Use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although as per normal get url conventions your url should look like

```
example.com/viewuser.php?user=5555
```

in above case you can geet the value required as

```
$user = $_GET['user'];
```

but if you insist in using like
    example.com/viewuser.php?5555
then you can get the required value as

```
$user = key($_GET);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on not using a traditional query parameter (with a key and a non-empty value), then do this:

```
$id = key($_GET);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you already have the URL with you and get "5555" in this example.

You can use regex.

```
preg_match("/\?(.+)/", $url, $matches);
if (!$matches) {
    // no matches
}

$result = $matches[1]; //5555
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has function [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) for parsing URL to its components, and [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to parse a query string into variables ( this function automatically urldecodes values ).

Example:

```
$url = "example.com/viewuser.php?5555";

var_dump( parse_url( $url ) );

/*
Array
(
    [path] => example.com/viewuser.php
    [query] => 5555
)
*/

$url = "example.com/viewuser.php?user=5555";
$query = parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY );    // user=5555
parse_str( $query, $params );

var_dump( $params );

/*
Array
(
    [user] => 5555
)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

eventually, i did it.
mansethaberler.php

```html
<?php include "header.php"; ?>
    <?php $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=boz_der; charset=utf8", "user", "ltmD38wbx"); ?>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 telefon-margin-top-slide">
    <?php include "solmenu.php"; ?>
    </div>
    
    <?php if($_GET) { 
    $verial = $_GET["git"];
    ?>
    
    <?php
    $veri = $db->query("SELECT * FROM haberlerekle WHERE haberekle_id='$verial'");
    ?>

    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

    <?php foreach ($veri as $haber) { ?>

    <div style="border:1px solid black; height:50px; background-color:#17a2b8; color:white; line-height:50px; text-align:center;"><?php echo $haber["habereklesayfasi_baslik"]; ?></div>
    <div class="row no-gutters">
    <img class="col-lg-12 mt-2" src="upload/images/<?php echo $haber["haberekle_resim"]; ?>" style="max-height:444px;">

    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12 ml-auto mt-1 mb-1" style="padding-left:7px;"><?php echo $haber["haberekle_konu"]; } ?></div>
    
    <?php } ?>
```

slider.php

```html
<?php
    $veriler = $db->query("SELECT * FROM haberlerekle ORDER BY haberekle_id DESC LIMIT 12",PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)->fetchAll();
    ?>
    
    <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($veriler as $row) {
        $actives = '';
        if($i == 0) {
            $actives = 'active';
        }
    ?>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="<?php echo $actives; ?>"></li>
    <?php $i++; } ?>
    </ul>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
  
      <?php
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($veriler as $row) {
        $actives = '';
            if($i == 0) {
            $actives = 'active';
            }
      ?>
    
      <?php $idcek = $row["haberekle_id"]; ?>
      
      <div class="carousel-item <?php echo $actives; ?>">
      <img src="upload/images/<?php echo $row["haberekle_resim"]; ?>" width="832" height="502"> <!-- upload/images/ ile <?php ?> tag'leri arasında boşluk olursa link kırılıyor. Resim çıkmıyor.  -->
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      <p><a href="mansethaberler.php?git=<?php echo $idcek; ?>"><?php echo $row['haberekle_baslik']; ?></a></p>
      </div> 
      </div>
    
      <?php $i++; } ?>
    
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
      </a>
      </div>
```

i added that codes in mansethaberler.php

```html
<?php if($_GET) { 
    $verial = $_GET["git"];
    ?>
```

and if this part

```html
<?php
    $veri = $db->query("SELECT * FROM haberlerekle WHERE haberekle_id='$verial'");
    ?>
```

='$verial'

i added that codes in slider.php

```html
<?php $idcek = $row["haberekle_id"]; ?>
```

and if this part

```html
<p><a href="mansethaberler.php?git=<?php echo $idcek; ?>"><?php echo $row['haberekle_baslik']; ?></a></p>
```

```html
 <a href="mansethaberler.php?git=<?php echo $idcek; ?>">
```

and anymore if i click which link, it is showing the other page.

Thank you everything.

Comment: Did you mistakenly post this answer here when it was the answer for a different question? Perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63486834/i-want-to-extract-data-from-the-database-by-link-in-other-page

Answer (score 0):

You simply use the `GET` request.

Example:
If you are looking to get ../?user=1

Then you do this:

`<?php echo $_GET['user']?>`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When adding an answer to a four year old question with an accepted answer it is a good idea to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses so that it doesn't get mistaken for a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

If your url is like this :
`example.com/viewuser.php?user=5555`

You can get the value attached to user with : `$_GET["user"]`